# How to upload large file to s3 using Server Actions in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, next.js, form-data, next.js13

I tried this code

```
// required package imported

async function createEntry(formData){
    "use server"
    // create entry in db
    
    const file = formData.get("avatar")
    console.log(file)
    const s3 = new S3({
        accessKeyId: 'xxx',
        secretAccessKey: 'xxx',
        region: 'xxx',
    });
    const params = {
        Bucket : 'xxx',
        Key: "xxx",
        Body: file
    }
    const upload = await s3.putObject(params).promise();;
    console.log(`File uploaded successfully`);
}

export default async function() {
    return(<>
        <form action={createEntry}>
            {/* other input fields */}
            <label>
                Select Picture
                <input type="file" name="avatar" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload Image"/>
        </form>
    </>)
}
```

It shows error 
`NetworkingError [NetworkingError]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received an instance of FileLike`

when I print the `file` to terminal it shows

```
FileLike [File] {
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    blobLike: FileLike [File] { [Symbol(state)]: [Object] },
    name: 'profile.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    lastModified: 1686755352774
  }
}
```

It works when I use some string instead of `file`.
The file size can be large so I want to stream the file to s3.
I don't want to use any additional packages.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to create a signed URL and post directly to that, so you don't have the upload going through your Next.js backend.